# how to get login user info in laravel blade outside middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the user id in a blade file that is outside of Laravel default Auth middleware. I was trying to get it by this code :

```
{{Auth::user()->id}}
```

But I am getting null response

Comment: You can't get it without middleware, but you can inject `user_id` on session when the user login, then you can get it without middleware from session

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, unfortunately, my stackoverflow point is too low to give your comment a like